# Dynamically Load Audio sound Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am trying to load an audio file which changes each time a request is sent to my PHP page. For some reason, my site does not like to open the new version of the file.

```
function reloadFile(command) {
    $.post("function.php", { data: command }, function(data) {
        console.log("Sever Says : " + data);
    }).done(
    function(data){             
        // Error In Here
        var audio = new Audio("a.ogg");
        audio.play();   
    });
}
```

Comment: Most likely because the browser cached it if the filename doesn't change. Try adding a timestamp to the URL, or change the server's cache settings

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's a great point ! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Browser only has the old audio loaded. You also need to send the changed audio file to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all of your help eventually I came to the conclusion that I would need to use the current server time to request the newly edited file in Apache and PHP.

The new code is as follows

```
var url = "filename.mp3?cb=" + new Date().getTime();
var audio = new Audio(url);
audio.load();
audio.play();
```